# Python decode file from multipart/form-data raw socket

Tags: python, sockets, http, decode

I'm trying to fetch multipart/form-data with raw socket. It works with regular inputs, but when I implement file type input I get

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position x: invalid start byte
```

error

form code

```
<form action="/login" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="file" name="files">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

recv func

```
    request = conn.recv(10240).decode()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> request = conn.recv(10240).decode()
> ```

This code assumes that you get the full body within a single read. But `recv` does not guarantee this. Instead the call only returns **up to** 10240 bytes in your case. The actual number of bytes depends on the amount of data send, how they are packetized on the wire, how large your socket buffer is and how many data are already received (and put into the socket buffer).

The proper way is to know up front on how many data to read and then use multiple `recv` calls until all data are read. This means that you need to read the HTTP header first to extract the `content-length` header which contains the amount of bytes in the body. In theory you would also need to deal with chunked transfer encoding but browsers don't use this in your specific case.

Apart from that what you get is bytes which are not in a specific encoding. This means using `decode` directly is wrong too. Instead you would need to parse the multipart MIME message based on the information in the header (i.e. MIME boundary) into its various parts and then you could `decode` the values in these parts but only when these values are actually encoded. For example, an uploaded file should not be decoded but treated as bytes instead. Even the other values might not be encoded in utf-8 as you assume - the exact encoding depends on the HTML you use and the snippet you show does not provide sufficient information about it.

In general: unless you really understand the relevant standards (HTTP and MIME) you  better use existing libraries. And if you understand the relevant standards you will likely use existing libraries too since you've realized how complex these standards are and that it would be a waste of time to implement these with all their edge cases by yourself.